# How can I write a line for all my views using their view model?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I am using the following line at the beginning of all my views:

```
<script> var viewModel = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)); </script>
```

I am doing that in order to manage the view model from my javascript framework but I prefer to centralize that line somehow instead of writing it in all my views, I am not sure if I can do it in a view layout since Razor does not know the view model type at that point.

How could I put that line in one single place for all my views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewData dictionary ( and the page Model) is available when razor executes the layout code.. So you can do this on layout.

```
<script>
    var mySecretApp = mySecretApp || {};       
    @if (!ViewContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        @:mySecretApp.pageViewModel = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
    }
    console.log('viewmodel', mySecretApp.pageViewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be using `ViewBag.MyViewModel` inside the `if` body?

Comment: @PeterB Actually Model is available in the layout ! So we do not really need to set and read from the view bag. ( that is why it worked for me with  the code i posted)